# What is the technical term for an anchor with a link to an id?

Tags: html, terminology

In german, we use the Term "Sprungmarke" which literally translates to "jump mark". What is the appropiate term in english?

```
<a href="#my-headline">Jump to My Headline</a>
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
<h1 id="my-headline">My Headline</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called "Fragment identifier":

- http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#navigating-to-a-fragment-identifier
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Identifying_resources_on_the_Web#Fragment
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

You can use id targets in a `href` to jump to a specific section with this id on the same page or any other.
You could also reference symbols in a SVG file.
This technique works across XML files.

Comment: Thank you very much. More sources to add to your post if you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Identifying_resources_on_the_Web#Fragment (look, I even added a fragment identifier) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier